# What is the best way to iterate while building a docker container?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to build a few docker containers and I found the iteration process of editing the Dockerfile, and scripts run within it, clunky.  I'm looking for best practices and to find out how others go about.

My initial process was:

1. `docker build -t mycontainer mycontainer`
2. `docker run mycontainer`
3. `docker exec -i -t < container id > "/bin/bash" # get into container to debug`
4. `docker rm -v < container id >`
5. `docker rmi mycontainer`
6. Repeat

This felt expensive for each iteration, especially if it was typo.

This alternate process required a little bit less iteration:

1. Install vim in dockerfile
2. `docker run mycontainer`
3. `docker exec -i -t < container id > "/bin/bash" # get into container to edit scripts`
4. `docker cp` to copy edited files out when done.
5. If I need to run any command, I carefully remember and update the Dockerfile outside the container.
6. Rebuild image without vim

This requires fewer iterations, but is not painless since everything's very manual and I have to remember which files changed and got updated.

Comment: a sidenote, you say `docker exec -i -t < container id > "/bin/bash" # get into container to debug` you can do `docker exec -i -t $(docker ps -lq) "/bin/bash"` so it is automatic

Comment: in fact you should do 2 and 3 in one command `docker run ... && docker exec...` so that you are sure to enter your container and not another one

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've been working with Docker in production since 0.7 and I've definitely felt your pain.

**Dockerfile Development Workflow**

Note: I always install vim in the container when I'm in active development. I just take it out of the Dockerfile when I release.

1. Setup tmux/gnu screen/iTerm/your favorite vertical split console utility.
2. On the right console I run:

   ```
   $ vim Dockerfile
   ```
3. On the left console I run:

   ```
   $ docker build -t username/imagename:latest . && docker run -it -name dev-1 username/imagename:latest
   ```
4. Now split the left console horizontally, so that the run STDOUT is above and a shell is below. Here you will run:

   ```
   docker exec -it dev-1
   ```

   and edits internally or do tests with:

   ```
   docker exec -it dev-1 <my command>
   ```
5. Every time you are satisfied with your work with the Dockerfile save (`:wq!`) and then in the left console run the command above. Test the behavior. If you are not happy run:

   ```
   docker rm dev-1
   ```

   and then edit again and repeat step #3.

Periodically, when I've built up too many images or containers I do the following:

- Remove all containers: `docker rm $(docker ps -qa)`
- Remove all images: `docker rmi $(docker images -q)`

Comment: thanks, what about all the extra containers and images that get created in the process?  Do you just ignore them?

Comment: Yeah, I ignore them and delete them en masse.

Answer (score 3):

I assume the files you're editing in your Alternate process are files that make up part of the application you're deploying? Such as a Bash or Python script?

That being the case, you could mount them as a volume, during your debugging process, rather than mounting them inside the docker, so that when you edit them, they are immediately changed within the docker and the host.

So for example, if your code is at /home/dragonx/codefiles, do

```
docker run -v /home/dragonx/codefiles:/opt/codefiles mycontainer
```

Then when you edit those files, either from the host or within the container, they are available in the container but you don't need to copy them out before killing the docker.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the simplest way to "build a few docker containers":

```
docker run -it --name=my_cont1 --hostname=my_host1 ubuntu:15.10
docker run -it --name=my_cont2 --hostname=my_host2 ubuntu:15.10
...
...

docker run -it --name=my_contn --hostname=my_hostn ubuntu:15.10
```

That would create 'n' number of containers.

After the very first "docker run ..." command, you will be put in a Bash shell. You can do your things there, exit and run the next "docker run ..." command.

Exiting from the Bash shell does not remove the containers. They are all still there in the "Exited" status. You can list them with the `docker ps -a` command. And you can always get back on to them by:

```
docker start -ia my_cont1
```

Comment: I think you isunderstood my question.  I know how to start/stop containers.  I'm talking about the process of editing the Dockerfile, cleaning up the old versions of the container, rebuilding, and relaunching.